# Button and text getting misplaced when i run in Emulator but in Design view it seems good in Android Studio 3.3.1

Tags: android

Button and text getting misplaced when I run in Emulator but in Design View it seems good in Android Studio 3.3.1.

This code appears good in the Design View as I added relative constraint in > this activity but when I run this code alignment of the button and > text get misplaced.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".secondactivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="86dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="user id"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.475"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.408" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="147dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="147dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="219dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="139dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="139dp"
        android:text="Admin Login"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

help me solve this problem .

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide screenshots both from Emulator and Android Studio Design Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `RelativeLayout` (that should be avoided most of the time) but at least the first control is using attributes meant for new `ConstrainLayout` (that `RelativeLayout` will be unable to use). Not sure how you are instantiating this layout, but all this is a red flag for sure.

You should at least show the different layouts (as @BenjyTec suggests) and how you're using this layout (are you using `setContentView()` in your `Activity`? are you inflating the layout and later attaching it somewhere?...)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting too many RelativeLayout constraints that contradicts with each other; also you're hard-coding margin/padding too many that won't fit every screen; instead you can solve this by putting widgets relative to each others and relative to their parent.

Please give this a try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".secondactivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="user id"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Admin Login"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You also need to try it on different screen sizes and orientation as you might change the top margin of the `textView3` upon that in order not to get the layout hidden off the screen. Constraint layout may be a better alternative in this case, I encourage you to give it a try.

wish that satisfy your need.